# How to programmatically lock an iPad app into one single application?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

we are doing a product display iPad app and don't want customers to be able to quit the app pressing the home button. We're planning to use only UIGesture to let the admin users to quit. How to programmatically lock an iPad app into one single application without install any third party app or profile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a feature for this added in iOS 6 Beta 2 called Guided Access, see http://www.idownloadblog.com/2012/06/26/ios-6-guided-access/

Answer (score 1):

- Install the iPhone Configuration Utility: http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US
- Make a `.mobileconfig` with the `SBStoreDemoAppLock` property set to `true`
- Install the mobile config on the device.

Installation of the mobile config can be done using either the iPCU app or by opening the file with Safari on the device.

Now the device is in kiosk mode and the home button is disabled.

Remove the `.mobileconfig` file (again using the iPCU app) and reboot the device to re-enable the home button.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the common solution to this problem is a case that covers the home and power buttons.    In practice, you'll want something that is fairly robust to prevent theft of the iPad, and that neatly covers access to the dock connector whilst providing power.

A quick google search of `iPad kiosk case` turns up plenty of options.  Use of iPads as PoS displays in stores and at trade shows is incredibly popular.